# Как занести данные из HTML-формы в MySQL при помощи JDBC?

Tags: html, mysql, jdbc

Имеются 2 HTML-формы

```
<input type="text" name="login" size="45" />
```

и

```
<input type="password" name="password" size="45" />
```

База данных на `MySQL Server`, где присутствуют аналогичные поля `login varchar (45) NOT NULL` и `password varchar (45) NOT NULL`.

Подскажите, как при помощи `JDBC` записать данные HTML-формы в БД `MySQL`. `PHP` не предлагать, можно другие Java-технологии.

Comment: Используйте наклоненную одинарную кавычку для внутристрочного кода: ` а не '

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема, в том как вытащить данные из формы или как сформировать запрос в БД ? Может покажите код который у вас имеется?

Comment: Кирилл, вытащил я данные вот так `var a=document.registration.elements[0].value;
var b=document.registration.elements[1].value;

Comment: А вот как именно записать в БД?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Быстрая реализация с использование сервлета:

**html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body id="body"> 
        <form method="post" action="TheFirstServlet">    
            <input name="login">
            <input name="password">
            <button>Записать</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**TheFirstServlet**

```
public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");  
    String login = request.getParameter("login");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");  
    insert(login, password);
    PrintWriter printWriter;
    try {
        printWriter = response.getWriter(); 
        printWriter.println("Ну, попытались");
    } catch(IOException exc) {}
}

public void insert(String login, String password) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc.url", "jdbc.login", "jdbc.password");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO NAME_TABLE (`login`,`password`)" +
            "VALUES ('" + login + "','" + password + "')";
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Не записал");
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if(conn!=null) conn.close();
            if(stmt!=null) stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException exc) {}
    }
  }
```

Ну, как-то так по-простому.

Comment: Очень признателен за помощь. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вот первый попавшийся пример который подходит под вашу задачу:

```
/STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCExample {
   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/STUDENTS";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "username";
   static final String PASS = "password";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
      System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();

      String sql = "INSERT INTO Registration " +
                   "VALUES (100, 'Zara', 'Ali', 18)";
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
      sql = "INSERT INTO Registration " +
                   "VALUES (101, 'Mahnaz', 'Fatma', 25)";
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
      sql = "INSERT INTO Registration " +
                   "VALUES (102, 'Zaid', 'Khan', 30)";
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
      sql = "INSERT INTO Registration " +
                   "VALUES(103, 'Sumit', 'Mittal', 28)";
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
      System.out.println("Inserted records into the table...");

   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
      }// do nothing
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}//end main
}//end JDBCExample
```

Comment: Дело в том, что здесь записываются конкретные величины, а не переменные `var`, в массив  к тому же вносится целая строка, а не конкретные значения в конкретные поля, с указанием номеров, что мне не нужно, ведь поле `user_id` в БД уже имеет параметр `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: @ЕгорВяземский вы часом не js имеете в виду?

Comment: Именно. А что, он не подходит для решения этой задачи?

Comment: @ЕгорВяземский окей, тогда причем здесь джава и JDBC?

Comment: @dDevil Кажется, я понял, в чём ошибка. Помнится, "Java to JavaScript - is as ham to hamster". Хорошо, как это тогда на Java реализовать? Чтение из HTML-формы и запись БД?

Comment: @ЕгорВяземский лол как-то. Ну, щас оформлю

Comment: Ну так запрос в БД можно и переписать! Но если вы пишете не на Java то этот пример вас не подходит!

Comment: @Kirill Stoianov Я уже понял свою ошибку. Что ж, тогда Java.